# Unable to call stored procedure from Python script

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I am unable to call a stored procedure from my Python script
Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc1`(IN weeks_history_param int,
    IN additional_weeks_param int, IN historic_run_param int, IN cv_folds_param int)
BEGIN

# First, anchor the query around the most recent Sunday
set @latest_sun = DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1 DAY);

select *
from customer_prescribing.manual_prescription_data
where ODS_Code = ods_code_param
and Date between
    date_sub(@latest_sun, interval weeks_history_param + additional_weeks_param + historic_run_param + cv_folds_param week) and
    date_sub(@latest_sun, interval historic_run_param week);

END
```

I can call the procedure from MySQL workbench without any problems.

The problem arises when I try to call it from Python.

Code:

```
import os
import mysql.connector

def data_ingestion():
   
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=ENDPOINT, user=USER, passwd=token, port=PORT, database=DBNAME)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        args = ("FF", 2, 2, 20, 3)
        result_args = cursor.callproc('path.proc1', args)
        for result in cursor.stored_results():
             print(result.fetchall())
        conn.commit()
        

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to execute stored procedure: {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if (conn.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_ingestion()
```

Error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.proc1_arg1' at line 1

Windows 10

Python version 3.9

MySQL version 8.0.23

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I was connected to another DB (DBNAME) and it does not know how to connect/call store procedures from another database.

Can you add an error message ?